# Why does this print the wrong part of the string?

Tags: c, c-strings

```
void buggy_substring(char *input, size_t pos, size_t len)
{
 input += pos;
 input[len] = '\0';
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 char name[16];
 strcpy(name, "Tessier-Lavigne");
 buggy_substring(name, 3, 2);
 printf("%s\n", name);
 return 0;
}
```

Why does this print "Tessi" instead of 'si'?
Is this an issue of mingling size_t with char?

Answer (score 2):

You change the start position only in the function. However, when printing you are still passing the original head of the  string to printf.

Try passing name+3 to printf .

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
     char name[16];
    // allocated a buffer of 16 bytes on the stack (called name)
    // note that an array of chars and a pointer to a char is NOT the same thing
     strcpy(name, "Tessier-Lavigne");
    // copies from a const null-terminated string 
    // now char* name contains
    // ['T','e','s','s','i','e','r','-','L','a','v','i','g','n','e','\0']
     buggy_substring(name, 3, 2);
    // name is passed as an immutable number "by value", 
    // the value of name is not changed
    // however, the contents name points to can be
    // now name is
    // ['T','e','s','s','\0','e','r','-','L','a','v','i','g','n','e','\0']


     printf("%s\n", name);
    //output 'T','e','s','s' + new line
     return 0;
    } 



    void buggy_substring(char *input, size_t pos, size_t len)
    {
    //local pointer input
    // points to ['T','e','s','s','i','e','r','-','L','a','v','i','g','n','e','\0']
    //pos=3
    //len=2
     input += pos;
    // input points to 's' (original name still points to 'T'

     input[len] = '\0';
    //equivalent code
     char * p=input;
     p+=len;
     *p='\0';
    // input+2 points to 'i'
    // 'i' is replaced with zero
    // the original buffer looks like
    //['T','e','s','s','\0','e','r','-','L','a','v','i','g','n','e','\0']
    }
```

*Disclaimer*: Of course you should he using library string manipulation functions for more serious code and don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: why does it stop at Tessi though? if buggy_substring doesn't do anything, shouldn't it print the whole thing?

Answer (score 1):

C is a pass-by-value language. Your `input += pos` in your substring function doesn't change anything about `name` in `main`.

Comment: why does it stop at Tessi though? if buggy_substring doesn't do anything, shouldn't it print the whole thing (Tessier-Lavigne)?

Comment: Oh it does modify the string buffer where you put the zero to the the setting. But the head of the buffer telling the same

Comment: @DrPhil why is that updated but not the head? I'm confused

Comment: i have updated my answer to give a trace of the code and how the buffer changes. The key is that the original pointer to the buffer doesn't change but the contents of the buffer do change

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a pointer *to the pointer* so that way the *pointer* gets modified, rather than the object being referenced.

```
void substring(char **input, size_t pos, size_t len)
{
 *input += pos;
 (*input)[len] = '\0';
}
```

Also would work if you pass pointer to array `char (*pa)[]`

Comment: why does it stop at Tessi though? if buggy_substring doesn't do anything, shouldn't it print the whole thing (Tessier-Lavigne)?

Answer (score 0):

Since C is pass-by-value, *copies* of the values which are provided as arguments are bound to the formal parameters in the function call. This means that, within `buggy_substring()`, `input` is a *copy* of the pointer value identified by `name` in `main()`. (Of course, `name` is an array of `char`, which decays to a pointer to `char` in the function call.)

Since `input` is but a copy of `name` (the pointer), any changes made to `input` (which is a pointer) cannot affect the value of `name` back in `main()`. But, `input` still points to the same location in memory as `name`, so changes made *through* `input` (a pointer) affect the same region of memory pointed to by `name` (the pointer).

The upshot of all this is that when the value of `input` is incremented it no longer points to the same memory location as `name` (the pointer). The incremented pointer can be used to write to memory with `input[len] = '\0'`, but when the `buggy_substring()` function returns, the lifetime of `input` ends (`input` is an *automatic variable*) and when back in `main()` `name` remains unchanged. So, when `printf()` is called, the string pointed to by `name` (the pointer: remember that array identifiers decay to pointers to their first elements in most cases) is printed from the beginning up to the newly inserted null-terminator.